# Search for items in a dataframe and transpose the columns to rows in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I  have a CSV  that  have  many  columns upto  400  and  I want  to search  through and get  only  the  rows with  the  yes and  no  transposed  so that  each question  one  can view  the  nos  example  of the data  is below

Sample  Data  is in the  following 
    https://pastebin.com/RgcE69KC

```
User  ['g3/af111c' 'g3/af112c' 'g4/af21c' 'g5/af34c' 'af43/af432c' 'cb3b/cb37c'
 'fv52/fv522c' 'fv52/fv523c']
```

Comment: Do you mind posting a csv or dataframe dump?

Comment: I have some real trouble understanding what you want

Comment: @danielmwai - Can you explain `User`, `User1` information? Maybe help if create small data sample - 10 columns, 3 rows and desired output. Thanks.

Comment: @Skirrebattie l ,  i have added  a link to  pastebin above for the data  am  using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

```
#read sample data - omit first column and last row (because it seems wrong data) 
df = pd.read_csv('https://pastebin.com/raw/RgcE69KC', nrows=9, usecols=range(1,12))
#add data for another user for better sample 
df.loc[range(5), 'User'] = 'Jan'
print (df)
  User cb43/cb431c cb43/cb431j cb43/cb432c cb43/cb433c cb43/cb434c  \
0  Jan         n/a         n/a         yes         yes         yes   
1  Jan         n/a         n/a         n/a         n/a         n/a   
2  Jan         n/a         n/a         yes         yes         yes   
3  Jan         n/a         n/a         yes         yes         yes   
4  Jan         n/a         n/a         yes         yes         yes   
5  Dan         n/a         n/a         n/a         n/a         n/a   
6  Dan         n/a         n/a         n/a         n/a         n/a   
7  Dan         n/a         n/a         n/a         n/a         n/a   
8  Dan         n/a         n/a         yes         yes         yes   

  cb43/cb435c cb43/cb436c cb43/cb437c            cb43/cb437j cb44/cb441c  
0         yes         yes          no   No records available         yes  
1         n/a         n/a         n/a                    n/a         n/a  
2         yes         yes          no   No records available         yes  
3         yes         yes         yes  No fertilizer applied         yes  
4         yes         yes         yes  No fertilizer applied         yes  
5         n/a         n/a         n/a                    n/a         n/a  
6         n/a         n/a         n/a                    n/a         n/a  
7         n/a         n/a         n/a                    n/a         n/a  
8         yes         yes          na  No fertilizer applied         yes
```

---

```
df = df.set_index('User')
#replace all non 'yes' and 'no' values to `NaN` and reshape
df = df.where(df.isin(['yes','no'])).stack().reset_index(name='val')
#get for each User unique columns names
df = df.groupby('User')['level_1'].unique().reset_index(name='un_val')
print (df)
  User                                             un_val
0  Dan  [cb43/cb432c, cb43/cb433c, cb43/cb434c, cb43/c...
1  Jan  [cb43/cb432c, cb43/cb433c, cb43/cb434c, cb43/c...
```

Comment: i  have added the bit  of  csv am  using   in the question  above  , i need also  to transpose  the data  and have the rows  now showing  which  headers  have  the nos

Comment: sorry, I am not sure if understand. If use your data `df = pd.read_csv('https://pastebin.com/raw/RgcE69KC', nrows=9, usecols=range(1,12))` what is desired output? Do you need `Dan`, another users and list of column names where are only yes or no values?

Comment: The  dan are  representations  of different users .and  the  columns  are  questions and  i want to group  them  per  dan  (who  is the user who answered the question  (the questions are the  cb43 to cb44 and  many  more ) , and then  using panda  i  can  be able to  group or  (transpose) and  see in  a summarized  list the user  who  has a  no  in one  of the questions  cb43-to cb44

Comment: OK, I try change answer, please check it. Thanks.

Comment: kindly  am  not  getting the  same result when  i  transpose  some  results in excel ,  i  have  updated  the  csv

Comment: It seems you need somrthing different. :( I think the best is create some small data sample and desired output. Because in your data sample is problematic see wahat you need, sorry. Maybe also [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) can be useful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148932/discussion-between-danielmwai-and-jezrael).